# Okta - Getting Unknown authentication strategy "oidc" in Express app

Tags: express, authentication, okta

I have followed the documentation exactly (https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/31/simple-auth-express-fifteen-minutes) for setting up Okta in my ExpressJS app but whenever I got to http://localhost:3000/login its giving me this error.

```
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "oidc"
    at attempt (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:190:39)
    at authenticate (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
    at /Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/@okta/oidc-middleware/src/connectUtil.js:80:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/student/Projects/week_10/ProcessReviewSite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: I am getting this as well with the same config as the tutorial. Seemed like it was working fine yesterday. Then it stopped working on local host last night, and the stopped working on azure hosted today--where I know I did not change a thing.

Comment: I'm getting this too on Lambda, but it works on local.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, but here is something that I hope can help.
Using the code from the repo, referenced in the article you linked, I had no error.
For reference, [here](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-node-express-15-minute-auth-example) is the link to the repo.

Be sure to install all the packages with `npm install` and to populate the `.env` file with the correct values for all the environment variables, which are:
`HOST_URL`
`OKTA_ORG_URL`
`APP_SECRET`
`OKTA_CLIENT_ID`
`OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET`
`OKTA_TOKEN`

Also make sure the configuration on Okta is correct - the article has a step-by-step guide to the configuration that should be there.

I stumbled upon the same error in a different context, but the example code works without issue, I was able to successfully login.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on my local. Here's my .env (properly redacted)

```
OKTA_ORG_URL=https://dev-69099605.okta.com
APP_SECRET=<application / session secret>
OKTA_CLIENT_ID=<client ID>
OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET=<client secret>
HOST_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

Then in Okta, I've created an application as described [here](https://toolkit.okta.com/apps/okta-nodejs-aws-lambda-example/). I disabled "Require consent" under "USER CONSENT" and added `http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback` as a login redirect URI under "LOGIN". I also have `http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback` for "Initiate login URI". It works on my local. It *doesn't* work in Lambda, but that's a separate matter. :)